# enumitem conflicts with galician

Tags: lists, babel, incompatibility, enumitem

The following code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[galician]{babel}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Preguntas e respostas}
\begin{enumerate}
\item{}\textit{Non aparece a imaxe do fondo.}
Se construíches o KLettres.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

generates

> Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 11.

The code works if I replace `enumitem` with `enumerate` or `galician` with `spanish`. But `enumitem` is needed to have unboxed style for descriptions.

Is there any way to avoid this conflict?

Comment: I don't think it's possible; `galician.ldf` heavily redefines the enumerate and itemize environment counter representations, thus conflicting with what `enumitem` tries to do.

Comment: @egreg: as I wrote in my answer, seemingly things look a bit better;).

Comment: @mbork One learns day by day. :)

Comment: @egreg: And it's an honour and pleasure for me to write here something *you* don't know:).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `enumitem` package has a `loadonly` option, which does not redefine existing list environments (`enumerate`, `itemize`, `description`), but lets you define your own ones (see its documentation).  For example:

```
\usepackage[shortlabels,loadonly]{enumitem}

\newlist{mydesc}{description}{2}
\setlist[mydesc]{style=unboxed}
```

not only works with `galician`, but defines a new `mydesc` environment, behaving like `description` (except that it is `unboxed` and has a maximum depth level of 2).

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to the preamble, after loading babel:

```
\makeatletter
\let\savegl@listquot\gl@listquot
\def\gl@listquot{\protect\savegl@listquot}
\makeatletter
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain what this is doing? Thanks for the enumitem package btw. I have a similar conflict with enumitem and Spanish in babel. I just want to double check if this solution would be useful, or how to modify it to solve my problem.