# enumitem conflict with french babel

Tags: babel, incompatibility, enumitem

The following crashes with the error:

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=20pt]
\item item1
\item item2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Works ok with english babel.
I tried the option loadonly like in [enumitem conflicts with galician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46559) but without success.
Crashes also with french babel.

---

I found a workaround:

use

```
 \begin{enumerate}[topsep=20pt,label=--]
```

instead of

```
 \begin{itemize}[topsep=20pt]
```

Comment: I have no problem here (`TeXLive2012` fully updated). Do you have an up to date version of both packages `babel` and `enumitem`?

Comment: It works without error in my texlive 2012, adding `\filelist` to the preamble shows the newest package that my system loads on that example is enumitem.sty    `2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists do you have an older/newer version?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a problem with the language setting of `frenchb.ldf`. Update your system, at least `babel` then it will work.

Comment: @cjorssen I'm using MikTeX 2.9, updated the packages : babel 3.8m and enumitem 3.5.2. Still doesn't work. Command \begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,topsep=20pt] works properly though.

Comment: babel should be `babel.sty 2013/04/15 v3.9e The Babel package`

Comment: Unfortunately not in MiKTeX until now …

Comment: BTW Also in my portable TeX Live 2012 for Windows is only babel 3.8m existant, and updating for known reasons not possible now.

Comment: Yes frenchb.ldf was old on my miktex version, thks

Answer (score 2):

When loading `[french]{babel}` with MiKTeX, use the following in the preamble:

```
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}   %% Resolves conflict between babel and enumitem
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

I am unaware of the exact workings behind the `[french]{babel}`package (I would much appreciate if someone could shed the light on the exact technical issue), but I do know that certain changes are made by babel regarding the interpretation of certain characters by LaTeX to allow for the appropriate output of lists according to french typographical standards. These changes are the cause of the conflict between `babel` and `enumitem`. The use of `\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}` will resolve this conflict.

Comment: very useful, esp on systems where you can not update babel! helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Load Babel at the end of your preamble.